# Как убрать строки из файла от одного ключевого слова до другого?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл, в котором такое содержание:

```
        CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
CLUSTERED BY (fv,
              sv,
              tv) 
SORTED BY (fv,
           sv,
           tv) INTO 2 BUCKETS;
-- more text afterwards
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт стирал все слова от Clustered включительно до Buckets включительно, но точку с запятой к примеру не стирал. Как можно реализовать код? Мне предлагали такой:

```
start_word = "CLUSTERED"
end_word = "BUCKETS"

result_lines = []

with open(target_file, 'r') as f:
    erasing = False
    for line in f:
        if not erasing and start_word in line:
            // begin erasing lines
            erasing = True
            continue

        if erasing and end_word in line:
            // finished erasing lines
            erasing = False
            continue

        if erasing:
            // we are between the start and end of the section we want to erase
            continue
        else:
            // either we haven't started erasing or we have already finished
            result_lines.append(line)

print('\n'.join(result_lines))
```

Но он стирает точку с запятой и вообще всё, что на строках с Clustered и Buckets. Результат должен быть приблизительно таким:

```
 CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
-- more text afterwards;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

воспользйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

#text = """
#CREATE TABLE some_name (
#fv int,
#sv int,
#tv int)
#CLUSTERED BY (fv,
#              sv,
#              tv) 
#SORTED BY (fv,
#           sv,
#           tv) INTO 2 BUCKETS;
#-- more text afterwards
#"""

with open(target_file, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
res = re.sub('CLUSTERED[\s\b\n\r]+[^;]*', '', text)
print(res)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
;
-- more text afterwards
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Можете дать хороший источник, почитать про регулярки?

Comment: @VadimYermolenko, можно попробовать начать [отсюда](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-regular-expression-tutorial)...

Answer (score 1):

Пример через регулярку:

```
import re

text = """\
CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
CLUSTERED BY (fv,
              sv,
              tv) 
SORTED BY (fv,
           sv,
           tv) INTO 2 BUCKETS;
-- more text afterwards
"""

new_text = re.sub('Clustered.+?Buckets;', ';', text, flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
CREATE TABLE some_name (
fv int,
sv int,
tv int)
;
-- more text afterwards
```